# Convert only a fraction of formula to absolute reference from relative reference

Tags: vba, excel

First off, I do apologize if it is a silly question, but I just couldn't find an answer anywhere online. I have a question to ask anyone who is familiar in changing relative formula to absolute formula using vba.

My problem right now is that, my absolute formula is determined by calculating row difference of different cell conditions of other columns (Column C) as I have input multiple formulas across a column (Column B) using vba. Hence the absolute formula that I want to achieve is unpredictable and it is constantly changing.

```
   Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(lastrow, 3))
        Range("B2").Select
        startb = lastrow
        For b = lastrow To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(b, 3) <> Cells(b - 1, 3) Then
        endb = b
        rowdiff = startb - endb
        Cells(end, 2).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Countif(RC[-1]:R[" & rowdiff & "]C[-1],RC[-1])"
        ActiveCell.Formula = Application.ConvertFormula(Formula:=ActiveCell.Formula, fromreferencestyle:=Application.ReferenceStyle, toabsolute:=xlAbsolute)
        Selection.Copy
        Range(Cells(startb, 2), Cells(endb, 2)).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        End If
        Next b
```

As you guys can see that I have a code line that can convert relative formula to absolute formula straight away. Unfortunately in my COUNTIF formula, I want an absolute range (the section before the comma) but a relative criteria (in this case the RC[-1] after the comma).

Is there anything I could do to just convert a partial formula to become absolute? Or there isn't such thing? Any help and advice is greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I am doing it in a completely wrong way.

Thank you for reading and your time.

Comment: does your code run without issues? There can not be any variable called after `end`. You use a variable called `lastRow` as a _column_ index. What's the actual goal of your code?

Comment: sorry about all the typos. I have edited accordingly. I was changing the names of the string earlier to a shorter name because the variable name was too long in my codes. forgotten about the impossible use of "end" as a variable. This code run without issues.

Comment: see my posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as to your very point of *partially* converting a formula from relative to absolute except for the last cell reference, you could use this function

```
Function LeaveLastRelative(strng As String) As String
    LeaveLastRelative = Left(strng, InStrRev(strng, ",")) & Replace(Right(strng, Len(strng) - InStrRev(strng, ",")), "$", "")
End Function
```

whose more verbose and (possibly) clear version is:

```
Function LeaveLastRelative(strng As String) As String
    Dim strng1 As String, strng2 As String

    strng2 = Right(strng, Len(strng) - InStrRev(strng, ","))
    strng1 = Left(strng, InStrRev(strng, ","))
    LeaveLastRelative = strng1 & Replace(strng2, "$", "")
End Function
```

to be used as:

```
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Countif(RC[-1]:R[" & rowdiff & "]C[-1],RC[-1])"
            ActiveCell.formula = Application.ConvertFormula(formula:=ActiveCell.formula, fromreferencestyle:=Application.ReferenceStyle, toabsolute:=xlAbsolute)
            ActiveCell.formula = LeaveLastRelative(ActiveCell.formula) '<--| here you use the function
```

Comment: Thanks user3598756 for your reply and help. The whole section of active cell formula has become absolute reference, like how was mine presented earlier. I tried both function of yours. Where have I done wrong?

Comment: my wrong: `Application.ConvertFormula()` doesn't return the converted formula, so it must be called by itself and then use the `LeaveLastRelative()` function on its result left in the cell. see edited answer

Comment: @Skyler, did you get through it?

Comment: yes it finally worked! it's fantastic and it's working well! thanks so much for that! I am not familiar with the [Right] and [Left] functions, and I will make sure to learn that well.