# Apply excel macro to first part of equation

Tags: excel, vba

How can I change the excel vba macro below to only work on the first part of A55*B66 and leave B66 as variable?

```
Sub Absolute()
'$A$1
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Selection
    If cell.HasFormula Then
        cell.Formula = Application.ConvertFormula(cell.Formula, _
        xlA1, xlA1, xlAbsolute)
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Seems like they have a formula like `=A55*B66` and they want to convert it to `=$A$55*B66`   Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232315/convert-only-a-fraction-of-formula-to-absolute-reference-from-relative-reference\

Comment: If the formulas in question are always products of two cells then this is somewhat trivial (split the formula on `*`, modify the first address, rejoin with `*`). Otherwise, you would need to clarify.

Comment: Ahh. Hardly seems like the kind of thing to use vba for.

Comment: John Coleman, I think you are on the right track. Can you show how to split it and only work on the first part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a somewhat ad-hoc answer which works in the special case of formulas which are the product of two cells:

```
Sub Absolute()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim factors As Variant
    For Each cell In Selection
        If cell.HasFormula And cell.Formula Like "*[*]*" Then
            factors = Split(cell.Formula, "*")
            factors(0) = Range(factors(0)).Address
            cell.Formula = "=" & Join(factors, "*")
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```